# ng-click not working on submit button

Tags: angularjs

I am learning how to use AngularJS, and I can't get a custom `ng-click` function to work. What I want to do is fire a `$http.post` request that contains data from my forms (`$scope.email`, `$scope.username`, `$scope.password`). So far I've tried only passing in email, but nothing happens when I click the submit button (there is no POST request fired, I am checking this with firebug). I tried passing it directly as `$scope.email`, or as a variable (as shown below).

I have a main page (index.html), that uses `ng-view` to load html using `ngRoute`. This the the route code:

```
.when('/register', {
        templateUrl: 'views/register.html',
        controller: 'RegisterCtrl'
      })
```

Here is my register.html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-3 col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <h1>Sign Up:</h1>
        <form>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email address:</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" ng-model="email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="username">Username:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" ng-model="username">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" ng-model="password">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-xs-5" ng-click="register">Sign up</button>
            <div class="col-xs-2"></div>
            <button class="btn btn-info col-xs-5">Go to log in</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

and my controller:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('angularApp')
  .controller('RegisterCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.email = '';
        $scope.username = '';
        $scope.password = '';

        $scope.register = function() {
            // TODO ADD VALIDATION
            var email = $scope.email;
            var username = $scope.username;
            var password = $scope.password;

            // $http request
            $http.post('http://localhost/PTC/API/new_user.php', email).
                success(function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }).
                error(function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                });
        };
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should have function `()` brackets to call function like `ng-click="register()"`

OR for more better way rather than using `ng-click` on form you could replace it with `ng-submit` directive

**Markup**

```
    <form name="myForm" ng-click="register()">
        ...fields here..
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-xs-5">Sign up</button>
        <div class="col-xs-2"></div>
        <button class="btn btn-info col-xs-5">Go to log in</button>
    </form>
```

Additionally you need to give form name to your form, so that you could get better controller over form validation.